# Magento 1.7 Fatal Error: Class 'Mage_Profile_Helper_Data' not found in Mage.php

Tags: php, class, magento

I keep getting this message when I try to go to a user profile page in the frontend. Can someone help me find a solution. I'm very new to Magento.

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Profile_Helper_Data' not found in /home/.../public_html/store/app/Mage.php on line 546

Also, I believe this was working recently but I have only made some css changes to the theme so not sure how I could have broken this.

I have also recompiled and disabled compilation from the admin panel.

Update:

I found this in Data.php:

```
class MYSITE_Profile_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

    public function getProfilesUrl(){
        return Mage::getUrl('profile/profile/index');
    }
}
```

And I found this in app/etc/modules/MYSITE_Profile.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MYSITE_Profile>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Core />
        </depends>
    </MYSITE_Profile>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create one file with name data.php in helper folder of profile module
. That's why you should always include Data helper in your extensions. So the following code in your `app/code/local/MYSITE/Helper/Data.php`

```
class Mage_Profile_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

and

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <profile>
            <class>MYSITE_Profile_Helper</class>
        </profile>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

in your `app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/etc/config.xml` should be enough.

Comment: Just to note, I think he is probably missing it from a custom module in local or community and the last place inheritance will check is Mage in core, I don't thing `Mage_Profile` is a core module anyway, it is all located within `Mage_Customer`

Comment: @input, that should be given error like not found `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` we can guess they create namespace module with `Mage` not by own one.

Comment: If someone created a module in `local/Mage/Profile/` it would throw the above error, I was just pointing out I don't think it is a core module.

Comment: @Steve Robbins. thanks to correct my post. it would throw error in xml if it in capital.

Comment: @liyakat, can you tell me where to put the data.php file and where is the config.xml file?

Comment: @liyakat, i don't have this directory:app/code/local/MYSITE/Helper/Data.php, but i do have this directory: app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/Helper/Data.php so i added the code there. and i added the xml to /app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/etc/config.xml but i still get same error. did i miss something?

Comment: pls change your helper class in xml with `MYSITE_Profile_Helper` also see my updated answer

Comment: @liyakat, thanks, but that already existed. i updated my post above with entire global tag that already existed.

Comment: have you changed your etc/modules/config.xml with new name like MYSITE ?

Comment: i have tried the ..etc/config.xml with and without your suggested xml. both gave the error still. i have also been trying to compile and clear cache but still get the error everytime

Comment: will pls add your config.xml here

Comment: i added the entire config.xml in the original post above

Comment: i am talking about app/etc/modules/your_module.xml files main config file

Comment: ah, ok. i updated the post with the correct xml file. do i add your xml suggestion inside that config tag?

Comment: IT WORKS NOW! So in the end all that was needed was to add the Mage_Profile_Helper_Data class to app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/Helper/Data.php and also maybe disabling 'Compiler Status' in compile settings in admin panel. Thanks a Million liyakat!

Comment: @user2754877, glad to help you. after long discussion of thread.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you are dealing with a custom module, as there is no `Mage_Profile` module. Typically, a "missing data helper" issue is the result of a module developer specifying to translate a string and failing to provide the appropriate class.

When Magento is asked to instantiate a helper (or block or model) class via its factory method, it takes the argument (`profile` in  this case) and tries to resolve it to a particular Xpath node. If the application doesn't find this node, it will assume the argument is part of the core, and so will prepend `mage_`, add the class type (`helper`), and append the class id (which for helpers is `data`). See [`Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L1213) for the specifics.

You will want to search XML files in *`app/code/community/`*, *`app/code/local/`*, and *`app/design/frontend/`* for the string `"profile"` (double quotes included). This is the most common vector for this issue.

It is also possible to instantiate helpers via several factory methods (unforunately). These can likely be discovered by grepping *`.php`* and *`.phtml`* files for the string `('profile')` or `('profile/data')`.

Ultimately you are looking for a custom module where you will need to configure the `profile` class group for helpers. This will be in e.g. *`The/Module/etc/config.xml`* and the what you will create/add will be the following:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <profile><!-- class group -->
            <class>The_Module_Helper</class><!-- class prefix -->
        </profile>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Then you need only define `The_Module_Helper_Data` class as follows (in e.g. *`The/Module/Helper/Data.php`*:

```
<?php
class The_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

After doing this, your application should work, and you should throttle the original developer :-)

Comment: i have question in my mind.if we can define our custom module with any mage namespace.? is it create any issue ?

Comment: Issue? Not technically, but it is not appropriate. `Profile` would be a bad module name as it is reasonable to think that Magento might release a module of the same name.

Comment: @benmarks, i found these: /app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/etc/config.xml, /app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/Model/Profile.php; Should I fix something there or add the XML and PHP code you posted. I tried to add the code but I don't know the file paths to these files (data.php & config.xml since there seem to be a few of each of these files)

Comment: @benmarks,ohh i am agree with you. yes there chance to see this type of named in future of magento version.

Comment: In *`app/code/local/MYSITE/Profile/etc/config.xml`* add the `global/helpers/profile/class` path with the `MYSITE_Profile_Helper` string. Then you will need to create the `MYSITE_Profile_Helper_Data` class as I describe.

Answer (score 0):

This Error is caused by autoloader.php file. To solve it don't use "_" in file name any where, specially in config.xml since, it will be replaced by "/" and throw such errors.

Ex:
giftcard_confirm.html

Insted use:
giftcardconfirm.html